# Check for user input while filling an empty list using a for loop with range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I did spend some time searching for an answer though I couldn't find one.
My first question here is a bit of an obvious one I'm sure... I just can't put my finger on the answer.

I'm trying to write this code so that when the user enters a name already in this list, the print statement will read, '*please enter a unique name*' or something along those lines.. and loop back to the beginning without effecting the total of 6 inputs.
I tried playing with a *while* loop and a few *for* loops but I couldn't get it right.

Thanks for reading and answering!

```
name_list = []
question = "Please enter a name: "

for i in range(6):
    name_list.append(input(question))

for name in name_list:
    print("- " + name.title())
```

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question. Hint: Use an infinite loop ("while True") and don't use a for-loop for the six inputs. Instead check how many valid inputs are in the list and break when six is reached.

Comment: Hey Michael I very much appreciate your quick answer. I see"Treatybreaker" has commented a full answer so I can save the embarrassment of posting what I was trying. While not *too* far off, it was more complicated than I thought.

I really like you encouragement and I'll definitely include a properly formatted attempt when I next run into a wall and have to post for some assistance. I'm about a week into coding so I'm sure it won't be long...

Regards,
Harry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some much more readable code.

```
names = []

while len(names) < 6:
    name = input("Please enter a name:\n").strip() # Remove spaces before/after

    if name.lower() in [x.lower() for x in names]:
        print("Name already in list, try again")
    else:
        names.append(name)

print("Names:\n" + "\n".join(names))
```

You don't need the break/continue statements. This is not the situation to use them in. Changing the user-input to lowercase is also breaking for some names.

Comment: In line 5 of your code, is the reason you introduce a new variable to loop through the list "names" because you can't loop through a list while adding to it?

for example you couldn't write:  
        if name.lower() in names:

Comment: @HarryCashel What you're seeing there is a list comprehension. It's creating a new list with only lowercase names. 'x' is just chosen because the variable is only ever used there, and doesn't need extra readability. You can do very cool stuff with list comprehensions like create filtered lists like [x for x in names if len(x) > 3]. This creates a list of only names over 3 characters long.

Answer (score 2):

```
name_list = []
added_new_name = 0
while True:
    new_name = input("Please enter a name: ")
    if new_name.lower() in name_list:
        print(f"{new_name} is already known! Please use a unique name.")
        continue
    else:
        print(f"Added {new_name.title()} to our database!")
        added_new_name += 1
        name_list.append(new_name.lower())
        if added_new_name >= 6:
            print("Done adding names!")
            print(f"Final Names:")
            for name in name_list:
                print(name)
            break
```

This for loop will run until 6 names have been entered. What's going on is the use of [continue and break statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) and then a separate counter that looks for how many names have been added and if a unique name is given I increment that counter and add the name in lowercase to the `name_list` and to check if the `new_name` is in the list I just do: `if new_name.lower() in name_list` which checks if the lowercase new_name is in the list which we are only appending lowercase strings to.

Comment: Hey breaker, this definitely solves what I was trying to accomplish. You saved me another hour I'm sure. It's a bit past my current understanding so I very much appreciate it.